# elasticsearch Best approach to ingest real time data (tweets)

Tags: elasticsearch

Basically, my application has 2 types of traffic.

Real-time tweets injection (can have delay up to 1 min)

Tweets search from multiple users

I have 2 questions

1. what is the best approach to ingest this data to elasticsearch

   What happens if I write tweets 1 at a time to elastic index in real-time? does it affect the "parallel search request"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index and searching are the two main operations in Elasticsearch and they have their own dedicated thread pools that work on these requests.

**Coming to your questions**

*1. what is the best approach to ingest this data to elasticsearch?*

You should not send these requests one by one and instead use the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to ingest the data, which is recommended and more performant for such use-cases. Also total size of Bulk operation matters in bulk API not the no of operations. [Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-bulk-indexing-with-spring) blog is a useful read on this.

*2.What happens if I write tweets 1 at a time to elastic index in real-time? does it affect the "parallel search request"?*

As mentioned that they have their own thread pools and if they are consumed you will see the issues in respective operation but there are various ways by which you can tune your indexing and search operations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why using bulk API is better than inserting data one by one?

Comment: @KaushikJ sure, but I would suggest you ask a separate question with some research and focus so that it would be helpful for others :)